# "Check in cannot proceed " while check in code in TFS

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am facing the following issue while check in the code on my TFS VS 2010.

[image]

I am stuck in my work. Please help to resolve my problem. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like somebody has turned on a custom Check-In policy on the server, but you don't have the Check-In policy installed locally.  It looks like it's the Custom Path Policy which is part of the TFS Power Tools.  Install the [TFS 2010 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) and try again.